# Issuing cmd-like commands in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line

I was wondering if its possible to open files in their default viewer using node.js

For instance, I can open a jpg on the command line by simply navigating to the directory and then typing the filename:

```
C:\Users\Fermion>sample.jpg
```

will open the sample.jpg file in Windows Photo Viewer.

Is it possible to write a JavaScript script that will issue the same command and run it using Node?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emulate the behavior of command prompt, all you would need to do is spawn a process with `cmd`.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var cmd = spawn('cmd');
cmd.stdin.write('sample.jpg\n');
```

In the example I've spawned a child process, and then I've written `sample.jpg\n` to its `stdin` stream. If you want to get output, you attach handlers to the other two streams.

```
cmd.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
  // the child process' stdout stream
});
cmd.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  // the child process' stderr stream
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to use node's `child_process` to spawn a terminal which you can then pipe your command to.

something similar to this http://www.dzone.com/snippets/execute-unix-command-nodejs

more information here:

http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html